# large graph data visualization with JDBC/ODBC

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-layout

I have looked at Gephi and tried to play around with it, however it only supports MySQL, SQLServer, and postgreSQL. My database connectivity is JDBC/ODBC. What other graph visualization software would be able to connect to such database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) is magnificent, it can handle enormously big data sets and draw graphs. But this is a standalone tool that draws graphs based on its own DSL, e.g.:

```
digraph G {
    A->B;
    A->C
}
```

So you would have to produce such a file first and then feed GraphViz with it.